# Laravel 4 Model Eloquent relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, model, eloquent

I've a quite complex user schema needings, I would like to know best way to build models in laravel 4. I tried to use pivot table but with no success. For semplicity I put only few fields per table.

**users**

- id
- name

**profiles**

- id
- provider

**addresses**

- id
- country_id
- city

**countries**

- id
- name

**companies**

- id
- name

**shops**

- id
- name

Here are the rules:

1. User can have many Addresses (shipping, billing...)
2. User can have many Profiles (Used for social login, on facebook, google...)
3. User can have many Companies (user can own multiple companies)
4. User can have many Shops (user can own multiple shops)
5. Profile can have one User
6. Address can have one User (an address can be referred to only one user)
7. Address can have one Company (an address can be referred to only one company)
8. Address can have one Shop
9. Address can have one Country
10. Country can have many Addresses
11. Company can have many Addresses (shipping, billing...)
12. Company can have many Shops
13. Company can have many Users
14. Shop can have many Addresses (shipping, billing...)
15. Shop can have many Users
16. Shop can have one Company

I'm not looking for "the" answer written down, I did the models but in my opinion the logic is not good enough. For example, here's the user and Address Class:

```
class User extends SentryUserModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
  public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany('Address');
  }
}

class Address extends Eloquent {
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

Building the models in such a way means that Eloquent expects to find in the address table the "user_id" field. In my opinion it should be better to use a pivot table, because address can belongs to users, companies and shops so is it better to have in the address table the user_id, company_id and shop_id table fields or use a three pivot tables (user_address, company_address and shop address)?

The pivot table will be built for sure for user and company, because it's a manytomany relationship.

---

After @MartinBean answer I want to thank him, but it works if in the User class I use

```
public function addresses() {
  return $this->morphMany('Address', 'addressable');
}
```

and in the Address class I use

```
public function addressable() {
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In this way I can easily print to retrieve the first current user address

```
$user->addresses->first()->address
```

and to retrieve the user email from the first address of the current user

```
Address::first()->addressable->email
```

But you pointed me to right direction I think, the polymorphic relationship, just for understanding it better why not pivot? And do you think pivot is anyway necessary for the user -- company relationship?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn’t a website to get professional developers to do work for you for free.

Comment: Hi @MartinBean, reading better my question you're right, it seems I request a work but this is not the case, I wrote an update, please roll back the down vote. Thanks

Comment: I made `Address` polymorphic because you wanted to be able to use addresses in multiple models. For joining models—like a user belonging to a company—then I’d use a pivot table.

Comment: If you could also keep your post so it covers one discreet question then that’ll help every one too, both those trying to answer and others who may be having the same issue as you and looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at addresses, you probably want to use a polymorphic relationship if you want it to be available for other models too. This would look like this:

```
<?php

class Address extends Eloquent {

    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('addressable');
    }

}
```

And then like this in your other models:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Address', 'addresses');
    }

}
```

There’s more information on polymorphic relationships here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks @MartinBean, just one consideration, I update the post